# why initialize reference succeeds with one constructor but not the other

Tags: c++, string, c++11, reference, initialization

Our code was using something like below, to pass a const string reference:

```
const char* str = // passed in;
const std::string& sym(str);
```

Then I need to fix it for take symbol only as the first 5 chars, I did:

```
const std::string& sym(str, 5);
```

but this throws me this compiling error:

```
error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
```

Why can I invoke the first constructor, but no the second one?

Comment: 1. Should that be `const std::string` and `const char*`? In any case if you want the first 5 chars you should be using `sym(str, 0, 5)`. If you are sure that str has 5 characters that is.

Comment: yeah I meant `const char*` but it is for string reference.

Comment: see https://godbolt.org/z/iVTEKr

Comment: As the referenced parameter should exist. Here your are creating temporary and referencing, I think.

Comment: So is the first case creating a temporary, why does it succeeds?

Comment: I'm actually suprised the first one works, but guess that a `std::string&` can refer to a `char *`. Basically it's the same as `const std::string& sym = str`. For the second, the result of `sym(str, 5)` is not an l-value so you will have to used `const std::string`

Comment: Str existing on stack... @ChrisD Agree I   am trying to say same thing. Referenced location should exist

Comment: @Mannoj yep. I got confused because I didn't think you could initialize references like that, but of course you can.

Answer (score 1):

Because the language doesn't allow that.

The `(...)` here don't invoke constructors of `std::string`, because the type of your variable is not an `std::string`, but a reference. Instead, `T &ref(x);` is just a different way to write `T &ref = x;`.

Note that in `const std::string& sym(str);`, since the type of `str` is `const char *` rather than a `std::string`, a temporary `std::string` is constructed and bound to the reference, and its [lifetime is extended](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary).

This makes `const std::string& sym(str);` mostly equivalent to `const std::string sym(str);` (but slightly more confusing).

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for initialization of references [[dcl.init.ref/5]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#ref-5):

> A reference to type “*cv1* `T1`” is initialized by an expression of type “*cv2* `T2`” as follows..

In your case

```
const std::string& sym(str, 5);
```

the expression is a **coumpound expression** `str, 5`. <s>Basically, it's the same as if you wrote</s>

```
const std::string& sym = (str, 5);
```

Which, in both cases, boils down to...

```
const std::string& sym = 5;
```

or

```
const std::string& sym(5);
```

My understanding is that the Standard allows initializing a reference only by a single expression, not by a pair of expressions separated by a comma.

<s>And, there is no matching constructor (which says the second error in your Godbolt demo).</s>

As a solution, you can write:

```
const std::string& sym{str, 5};
```

since, according to [[dcl.init/17.1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.1):

> If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list* or is `=` *braced-init-list*, the object or **reference is list-initialized**.

Comment: *"Basically, it's the same as if you wrote `const std::string& sym = (str, 5);`"* I'm not sure about that. Both GCC & Clang reject `std::string a; const std::string& sym(a, a);`.

Comment: why the fist initialization succeeds?

Comment: @fluter Because a reference can be initialized only by a (single) expression. But cannot be initialized by a pair of expressions separated by comma. At least, this is my understanding of the Standard.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Right, I believe the Standard does allow to initialize a reference only by a (single) expression, not by a pair of expressions separated by comma. Note that `const std::string& sym((a,a));` works, but `const std::string& sym((a,4));` does not.